# Retrieve recursive group membership of an Active Directory user or group in VBS

Tags: vbscript, active-directory

There are a lot of examples on how to use the memberOf property, but i could not find any working scripts that were to my need. So I wrote my own and I hope that sharing my script here will help others.

The script below has 2 working examples. The first example `Set GroupsOfUser = GetMembership(oAD.UserName, null)` retrieves the membership of the currectly logged on user. The second example `Set GroupsOfGroup = GetMembership("CN=SomeGroup,OU=MyGroupContainer,DC=MyDomain,DC=local", null)` demonstrates the membership of a specific group.

The function below returns unique values and does not get in an infinite loop as most examples do.

Comment: Good intention but there no question here. I doubt if that match the SO rules.

Comment: @seeker: The ask question said 'aswer your own question Q&A style' so i figured they encouraged this. Do you know of any other place to share such scripts? I've just posted another one..

Comment: Yes, they encouraged this, but also said "phrase it in the form of a question", this is what I mean by "no question here". Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

```
'Get the recursive groups from the active user
Set oAD = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
Set GroupsOfUser = GetMembership(oAD.UserName, null)
MsgBox Join(GroupsOfUser.Items(), "," & vbCrLf)

'Get the recursive groups from a specific group
Set GroupsOfGroup = GetMembership("CN=SomeGroup,OU=MyGroupContainer,DC=MyDomain,DC=local", null)
MsgBox Join(GroupsOfGroup.Items(), "," & vbCrLf)


Function GetMembership(sChild, dMembership)
  'Get AD info on the given Child
  Set oChild = GetObject("LDAP://" & sChild)

  If TypeName(oChild) = "Object" Then
    'Add the Child's canonical name to the array IF it's a group
    If TypeName(dMembership) = "Dictionary" Then
      dMembership.Add oChild.distinguishedName, oChild.CN
    Else
      Set dMembership = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    End If

    'If the Child has any parents (=groups), run the same loop for these parents.
    If TypeName(oChild.memberOf) = "Variant()" Then
      oParents = oChild.GetEx("memberOf")
      For Each sParent in oParents
        If Not dMembership.Exists(sParent) Then
          Set dMembership = GetMembership(sParent, dMembership)
        End If
      Next
    End If
  End If

  Set GetMembership = dMembership
End Function
```